# Simple Scala Mind Bender with Closures/Higher Order Functions/Methods

Tags: scala

I was playing around with Scala when I noticed that the code below does not compile, why ?

```
case class A(a:Int) {
   def getA: ()=>Int = () => a
   def getAA()=a
   def getAAA=a
}

object Test extends App{
  val a =A(3)
  def printInt(f:()=>Int)=println(f())
  printInt(a.getA)    // fine, prints 3
  printInt(a.getAA)   // fine, prints 3
  printInt(a.getAAA)  // this does not compile, why ?
}
```

What is the difference between a.getA, a.getAA and a.getAAA ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define a `def` without parentheses, you define it `val`-like. That means, it must be called without parentheses (otherwise they would be optional). `a.getAAA` has type `Int`.

When you define a `def` with (empty) parentheses, the use of parentheses on the caller side is optional *unless* it is used in a context where a function is also valid. Then the variant without parentheses is taken as a function.

In short, the following types are possible:

```
scala> a.getAAA : Int
res: Int = 3

scala> a.getAA() : Int
res: Int = 3

scala> a.getAA : Int
res: Int = 3

scala> a.getAA : (() => Int)
res: () => Int = <function0>
```

Not possible are:

```
scala> a.getAAA() : Int
<console>: error: Int does not take parameters
   a.getAAA() : Int
           ^

scala> a.getAAA : (() => Int)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: () => Int

scala> a.getAA() : (() => Int)
<console>: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: () => Int
```

If you want to use `getAAA` in a function context, you can make it an ad-hoc function with `printInt(a.getAAA _)`.